# R: Sentimentanalyse with quanteda package - groups does not work -> Error: groups must have length ndoc(x)

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, quanteda

this is my first Question, i hope someone can help, i really dont know what else to do.

So its about the website:
http://inhaltsanalyse-mit-r.de/sentiment.html There is an example on how to make an Sentimentanalyse, which I want to do. It is this code:

```
if(!require("quanteda")) {install.packages("quanteda"); library("quanteda")}
if(!require("readtext")) {install.packages("readtext"); library("readtext")}
if(!require("tidyverse")) {install.packages("tidyverse"); library("tidyverse")}
if(!require("scales")) {install.packages("scales"); library("scales")}

theme_set(theme_minimal())

////

load("daten/twitter/trumpclinton.korpus.RData")

korpus.stats.monat <- ungroup(korpus.stats.monat)
korpus.stats.monat

///

korpus.trump <- corpus_subset(korpus, Kandidat == "Trump")
meine.dfm.trump <- dfm(korpus.trump, groups = c("monat", "jahr"), dictionary = sentiment.lexikon)

sentiment.trump <- convert(meine.dfm.trump, "data.frame") %>%
  gather(positive, negative, key = "Polarität", value = "Wörter") %>% 
  mutate(Datum = as.Date(paste("01", doc_id, sep = "."), "%d.%m.%Y")) %>% 
  filter(Datum >= "2015-04-01" & Datum <= "2017-04-01")

ggplot(sentiment.trump, aes(Datum, Wörter, colour = Polarität, group = Polarität)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) + 
  scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 months", date_labels = "%b %Y") + 
  ggtitle("Sentiment-Scores für Donald Trump") + xlab("Monat") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

which gives me this:

```
meine.dfm.trump <- dfm(korpus.trump, groups = c("monat", "jahr"), dictionary = sentiment.lexikon)
```

> Error: groups must have length ndoc(x) In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: 'dfm.corpus()' is deprecated. Use 'tokens()' first.  2: 'groups' is
> deprecated; use dfm_group() instead

so i rearranged it to have it updated, maybe the older version was the problem:

```
korpus.trump <- corpus_subset(korpus, Kandidat == "Trump")
korpus.trump.tokens <- tokens(korpus.trump)
meine.dfm.trump <- dfm(korpus.trump.tokens)
meine.dfm.trump.group <- dfm_group (meine.dfm.trump, c(monat, jahr))
```

Which still gives me this:

> Error: groups must have length ndoc(x)

I have understood that it means that the object is kind of not long enough?
But when I look at monat and jahr in the dfm it shows me under "type" character[11221] for both, so they should have the same length.

It works when i just use monat or jahr. But then the plot does not show me anything but the names at the side

Answer (score 2):

To solve your issue you need to reorganize the code a bit. Quanteda has changed a bit since the site "Automatisierte Inhaltsanalyse mit R" was created.

The bit you need to change is below.

```
....
meine.dfm.trump <- tokens(korpus.trump) %>% 
    dfm() %>% 
    dfm_group(groups = interaction(monat, jahr)) %>% 
  dfm_lookup(dictionary = sentiment.lexikon)
....
```